# N-ary trees in C

Tags: c, struct, n-ary-tree, abstract-data-type

Which would be a neat implemenation of a N-ary tree in C language?

Particulary, I want to implement an n-ary tree, not self-ballancing, with an unbound number of children in each node, in which each node holds an already defined struct, like this for example:

```
struct task {
  char command[MAX_LENGTH];
  int required_time;
};
```

Comment: By N-ary, you mean a tree with fanout-degree N?  You have to specify more, for example not-self-balancing search tree, trie, B-tree, etc.

Comment: You are right, I'll edit the question to add some more detail. Thanks!
And thanks Matt J too for your answer!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As a first pass, you could simply create a *struct* (let's call it *TreeNode*) which holds a *task*, as well as a set of pointers to *TreeNode*s.  This set could either be an array (if **N** is fixed) or a linked list (if **N** is variable).  The linked list would require you to declare an additional *struct* (let's called it *ListNode*) with a *TreeNode* pointer to the actual child (part of the tree), and a pointer to the next *ListNode* in the list (**null** if at the end of the list).

It might look something like this:

```
struct task {
  char command[MAX_LENGTH];
  int required_time;
};

struct TreeNode;

struct ListNode {
  struct TreeNode * child;
  struct ListNode * next;
};

struct TreeNode {
  struct task myTask;
  struct ListNode myChildList;
};
```

Answer (score 56):

Any n-ary tree can be represented as a binary tree where in each node the left pointer points to the first child and the right pointer points to the next brother.

```
             R                        R
           / | \                      |
          B  C  D                     B -- C -- D
         / \    |                     |         |
        E   F   G                     E -- F    G
```

So, your case would be:

```
struct task {
  char command[MAX_LENGTH];
  int required_time;
};

struct node {
  struct task taskinfo;
  struct node *firstchild;
  struct node *nextsibling;
};
```

This technique has the advantage that many algorithms are simpler to write as they can be expressed on a binary tree rather than on a more complicated data structure.