# c++ library useful for making trees

Tags: c++, tree

I want to use vocabulary trees (which is not necessarily binary) in my program and I already have a general idea on how to create a tree class but I was wondering if there are any c++ libraries that are useful for that purpose. If not I would like to know about the methods I can use to manage my tree faster( add/remove/access nodes), like storing them in consecutive memory locations.

thank you

Comment: Storing in consecutive memory will become at least difficult if you don't know a priori how many children a node has.

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/205985/706456)

Comment: yea I know it's a problem. That was just an example I'm looking for good methods of implementing a tree. Of course I'd prefer a useful library or existing class for it. tnx

Comment: thank you, that post seems to answer my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [The Boost Graph Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html) to model all kinds of trees.

Answer (score 2):

Though `std::map` and `std::set` get mentioned in oleskii's [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205945/why-does-the-c-stl-not-provide-any-tree-containers/205985#205985) they are binary trees. Any [n-ary tree can be rearranged to a binary tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15126977/binary-representation-of-n-ary-tree), but that may not help you, since the re-organisation will take time. The boost graph libraries are more general purpose.

A quick google for n-ary trees C++" just turned up [treetree](https://code.google.com/p/treetree/)

> "Treetree is a header-only C++ library that implements a generic
>   tree-structured container class according to STL conventions"

If you want to make you current tree implementation faster, you should *measure* where it is currently slow.

Check simple things, e.g. make sure you pass by reference rather than by copy.