# Multi branch tree in c

Tags: c, data-structures, tree

I want to create a multi branch tree in c, can you guys please help me out.

Tree structure:

```
                  O
                 /|\
                / | \
               O  O  O
              /|\     \
             / | \     \
            O  O  O     O
```

Comment: Try first with simple [BST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) tree and then extend it to fulfil your task

Comment: Will the number of branches for a node be the same everytime? or will the no. of branches vary?

Comment: You may want to check:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189855/n-ary-trees-in-c

and

Comment: Number of branches will vary runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Most common approach is First-Child/Next-Sibling tree. It uses only 2 pointers to keep any number of children, not unlike linked list.

```
typedef struct node {
    struct node *child;
    struct node *next;
} node;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic tree structure:

```
typedef struct node {
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
    char *string;
} node;
```

You can easily extend it for more branches by holding an array of pointers to node instead of just left and right but it won't be that efficient.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of child nodes is fixed, or has a maximum number, you can use a pointers array:

```
typedef struct node {
    struct nodes *childs[];
    char *string;
} node;
```

Or you can dynamically allocate it:

```
typedef struct node {
    struct nodes **childs;
    char *string;
} node;
```

This allows direct access to the childs.
Another option is to use linked list to hold the childs. This way you can add/remove as many as you'd like, but you lose the direct access.